# clsid64 is null - registry cannot be read

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am trying to read a registry to access a Firebird asset. The code throws a NullReferenceException but I can guarantee the link is correct, so it leads me to think there is something wrong with the code.
Here is the ReadKey method:

```
using (var clsid64 = view64.OpenSubKey(keyPath, false))
{
    var installPath = clsid64.GetValue(valueName);
    return Convert.ToString(installPath);
}
```

And here is the OpenSubKey method, which is, in my opinion, the origin of the bug:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public RegistryKey OpenSubKey(string name, bool writable)
{
    ValidateKeyName(name);
    EnsureNotDisposed();
    name = FixupName(name);
    CheckPermission(RegistryInternalCheck.CheckOpenSubKeyWithWritablePermission, name, writable, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
    SafeRegistryHandle hkResult = null;
    int num = Win32Native.RegOpenKeyEx(hkey, name, 0, GetRegistryKeyAccess(writable) | (int)regView, out hkResult);
    if (num == 0 && !hkResult.IsInvalid)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = new RegistryKey(hkResult, writable, systemkey: false, remoteKey, isPerfData: false, regView);
        registryKey.checkMode = GetSubKeyPermissonCheck(writable);
        registryKey.keyName = keyName + "\\" + name;
        return registryKey;
    }

    if (num == 5 || num == 1346)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource.Security_RegistryPermission);
    }

    return null;
}
```

I tried to use both the view64 and view32 versions of the code, I double checked the link to the Firebird registry.

Comment: I don't see what your question has to do with the Firebird DBMS, so I removed the tag [tag:firebird] (and added the missing tag [tag:c#]). That said, your question seems to be missing a [mre].